# Data get appended from previous event in data layer of Enhanced E-Commerce

Tags: ios, events, append, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I implemented code as per official documents of Google Tag Manager.
Data is getting properly shown on dashboard of GA.
but i am facing weired issue of appending previous event Data to current event data.
For e.g. I send data for promotion banner on home page, that works fine.
Then product listing page, i send impression of each products; in this event previous promotion banner data get appended.
This happens to each event after promotion banner on home page.
What could be my mistake or probable solution?

Answer (score 1):

I used below code for solve this issue in swift 2.3:

```
let dataLayer: TAGDataLayer = TAGManager.instance().dataLayer

dataLayer.push(parameters) // parameters is dictionary data that you want to push

dataLayer.push(["ecommerce" : []])
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Tag Manager dataLayer is persistent for apps (this is not the case for web). This means that anything you push onto the dataLayer on one screen, will continue to exist on the dataLayer until the app is closed. So it is your responsibility as a developer to "remove" things from the dataLayer. You do this by pushing a `null` value onto the dataLayer for the `ecommerce` key. So in your case, immediately after pushing the product impression data onto the dataLayer, you should execute

`[dataLayer push:@{@"ecommerce":null}]`

This will "clear" the value of the `ecommerce` key so that it is not picked up by future tags.

Comment: @ faridghar : I already implemented this strategy in code, but still not working. Any other suggestion or trial?

Comment: Great to hear. Could you clarify what the little changes were so that other people can benefit? Thanks.

Comment: i posted answer below.

Comment: out of curiosity, could you try to push `nil` instead of `null`?

Comment: I am using Swift 2.3 language, null is not there in swift. We have to use nil only, but dictionary value of push is not optional, that why i used code :  dataLayer.push( ["ecommerce" : [] ] )